# Mobile header image too small

Tags: css, wordpress

I've installed a WordPress theme and having an issue on mobile, the header image is too small and obscuring the header text - http://www.stayinblackpool.co.uk/ anyone knows how to fix this?

Also, the header images appear to be darker but I can't see an opacity being applied. Any help would be gratefully received!

Tried to change the opacity to 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say, you want you logo 250px width, then, place this code in your media queries:

```
img.custom-logo {
    width: 250px;
}
```

And here is the css for your text:

```
.featured-image .page-title {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 26px;
    padding: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Nice, do not forget to mark this question as answered.